# Moq setup params linq includes

Tags: entity-framework, linq, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I've broken a lot of my unit tests when I've added some more includes as I'm not using Lazy Loading in EF. Before my Mock was setup line this:

```
  mockDocRepo.Setup(
            x => x.GetBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Doctor, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Doctor, object>>>()))
            .Returns(stubDoctor);
```

Which worked fine for a single include however adding another include when calling GetBy breaks all my tests. For example:

```
 var doctor = _dbContextScope.Repository<Doctor>().GetBy(x => x.Id == DoctorId, y => y.Contracts, y => y.Leave.Select(x => x.Type));
```

I've tried changing my Moq setup to accept an array e.g `It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Doctor, object>>[]>()` however this doesn't seem to work. I also tried just adding the second include in the setup 
e.g

```
mockDocRepo.Setup(
            x => x.GetBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Doctor, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Doctor, object>>>(),It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Doctor, object>>>()))
            .Returns(stubDoctor);
```

It seems to be the `.Select(x => x.Type)` in the final include that breaks everything.

Any ideas on how to fix this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think can do a MOQ setup Linq [Enumerable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) method. It is a static method on Enumerable class.

Using Moq, you cannot mock/setup on static methods, .In order to setup it has to be a virtual method.

Alternatively try to abstract DbContext and wrap the .select in a virtual method. Then you should be able to do the setup.